# Using Timer to coincide with Time, using PasteSpecial Only values and copy data row to row plus one

Tags: vba, excel

@simoco has been very helpful(basically, gave the whole code)

I now want to make some changes which I need a little tweaking, hope everyone can help:

Code:

```
Public currentRow As Range ' range with number of row in which the value should be    inserted'
Public sheetName As Range 'range with sheet name in which the value should be inserted'
Public mainworkBook As Workbook
Public stopTimer As Boolean ' variable to indicate whether to call timer again or not'

Sub Initiate()

   Set mainworkBook = ThisWorkbook
   ' the first line where you want to insert the value'
   Set currentRow = mainworkBook.Sheets("params").Range("a1")
   'name of the sheet in wich we will paste data'
    Set sheetName = mainworkBook.Sheets("params").Range("b1")

 stopTimer = False


 Call MoveData
End Sub

Sub Activate_timer()
   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:60:00"), "MoveData"
End Sub

Sub MoveData()
    mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(3).EntireRow.Copy
    mainworkBook.Sheets(sheetName.Value).Range("A" & currentRow.Value).PasteSpecial   xlPasteValues

  'increment the counter so the next time insert values to an empty string'
   currentRow.Value = currentRow.Value + 1

   'if all rows are filled'
  If (currentRow.Value = Rows.Count + 1) Then
      Call ChangeSheet
  End If

 If (Not stopTimer) Then
    Call Activate_timer
 End If

End Sub

 Sub ChangeSheet()
   Dim currentSheet As Range

   Set currentSheet = sheetName

   'determine what the next sheet name should be (you can add your own mapping)'
   Select Case currentSheet.Value
      Case "Sheet1":
           sheetName.Value = "Sheet3"
      Case "Sheet3":
           sheetName.Value = "Sheet4"
      Case "Sheet4":
           sheetName.Value = "Sheet5"
      Case Else:
           MsgBox "There is no sheets any more"
 End Select

   'if we didn't change sheet'
  If (currentSheet.Value = sheetName.Value) Then
       stopTimer = True
      Exit Sub
   End If
   ' copy and paste headers (where A1:F1 - is a range of headers, you should write actual address)'
 mainworkBook.Sheets(currentSheet.Value).Range("A1:F1").Copy
 mainworkBook.Sheets(sheetName.Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  'copy last row to the new sheet
 mainworkBook.Sheets(currentSheet.Value).Rows(Rows.Count).EntireRow.Copy
 mainworkBook.Sheets(sheetName.Value).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 ' make new value for the current row on the new sheet (where we will paste new values)'
 currentRow.Value = 3
End Sub
```

Edit: Getting a debug error in MoveData, code which gets highlighted:
    mainworkBook.Sheets(sheetName.Value).Range("A" & currentRow.Value).PasteSpecial   xlPasteValues

I have added a new sheet and renamed it "params", The error: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of Range

Thanks.

Comment: Reading tutorials is helpful and you should do it. We're here to answer questions which have not been answered before. We're not here to do your programming work.

Comment: @ThomasW.Thanks for your input, I am doing the tutorials(MSDN one for VBA at the moment).

Comment: Using the VBA Object Browser (F2) and Help (F1) are great resources when learning how to program. Have you tried searching PasteSpecial in the Object Browser?

Comment: Thanks Mark, I tried them and they are very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code. I've tried to comment it in details, but if you have some questions, please, ask.

Public variables

```
Public currentRow As Range ' range with number of row in which the value should be inserted'
Public sheetName As Range 'range with sheet name in which the value should be inserted'
Public mainworkBook As Workbook
Public stopTimer As Boolean ' variable to indicate whether to call timer again or not'
```

Init sub (you should call it in the ribbon to get macro work)

```
Sub Initiate()

   Set mainworkBook = ThisWorkbook
   ' the first line where you want to insert the value'
   Set currentRow = mainworkBook.Sheets("params").Range("a1")
   'name of the sheet in wich we will paste data'
   Set sheetName = mainworkBook.Sheets("params").Range("b1")

   stopTimer = False


   Call MoveData
End Sub
```

Timer:

```
Sub Activate_timer()
   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "MoveData"
End Sub
```

MoveData:

```
Sub MoveData()
   mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(3).EntireRow.Copy
   mainworkBook.Sheets(sheetName.Value).Range("A" & currentRow.Value).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

   'increment the counter so the next time insert values to an empty string'
   currentRow.Value = currentRow.Value + 1

   'if all rows are filled'
   If (currentRow.Value = Rows.Count + 1) Then
       Call ChangeSheet
   End If

   If (Not stopTimer) Then
      Call Activate_timer
   End If

End Sub
```

If we fill all rows in the sheet:

```
Sub ChangeSheet()
   Dim currentSheet As Range

   Set currentSheet = sheetName

   'determine what the next sheet name should be (you can add your own mapping)'
   Select Case currentSheet.Value
       Case "Sheet1":
           sheetName.Value = "Sheet3"
       Case "Sheet3":
           sheetName.Value = "Sheet4"
       Case "Sheet4":
           sheetName.Value = "Sheet5"
       Case Else:
           MsgBox "There is no sheets any more"
   End Select

   'if we didn't change sheet'
   If (currentSheet.Value = sheetName.Value) Then
       stopTimer = True
       Exit Sub
   End If
   ' copy and paste headers (where A1:F1 - is a range of headers, you should write actual address)'
   mainworkBook.Sheets(currentSheet.Value).Range("A1:F1").Copy
   mainworkBook.Sheets(sheetName.Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

   'copy last row to the new sheet
   mainworkBook.Sheets(currentSheet.Value).Rows(Rows.Count).EntireRow.Copy
   mainworkBook.Sheets(sheetName.Value).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

   ' make new value for the current row on the new sheet (where we will paste new values)'
   currentRow.Value = 3
End Sub
```

Hope it works:)

Comment: is it possible to remove the timer and set-it up in such a way as to input the value as and when the row has changes? Working through the VB course over at MSDN is it the right way to go or? Thanks :)

Comment: Oh and I just noticed that when the worksheet is closed and re-opened it starts pasting the values as per the reference given in the code and not where it left off. Guess I will change it every time before hitting initiate.

Comment: 1) i think yes, it is possible. 2) you can modify the macro to find first empty row in list and starts from it.

Comment: I've added some modifications to my answer. Now __currentRow__ and __sheetName__ variables are stored in the sheet called **"params"** (you need to create it, or change my code to store values in other place). This solves the issue with closing book.

Comment: Hi Simoco, sorry for all the trouble. I have edited the opening post after using the changed code. Please see. Thanks :)

Comment: 1) check please, if the name of new sheet is actually "params" (not "Params" or sth like this) 2)  check if on the list "params" you have correct _sheetName_ value in range "B1" and correct _currentRow_ value in range "A1" 3) try to add `MsgBox sheetName.Value` and `MsgBox currentRow.Value` before the line of code where error occurs and tell me what they are.

Comment: Hi, the sheet "params" has (Name) Sheet3, Name:params.
I tried inserting the MsgBox SheetName.Value and MsgBox currentRow.Value but it simply gives me the error 9 subscript out of range.

Comment: Open, please, the "params" sheet and say what in A1 and B1 ranges?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you are asking if there is any content in A1 B1 cells? If yes, they are empty. In fact the entire sheet "params" is empty. Wish I could just show you the workbook. I appreciate all the help :) Is it ok to link to dropbox or something here?

Comment: Yes, I'am asking exactly about this. They shoudn't be empty. In A1 should be number of first row where you want to paste values (i.e. 102), in B1 should be name of the sheet where to paste values (i.e. Sheet1)

Comment: Made the changes. Works perfectly now. Thanks. :)